# entries.saveEntry not triggered by ResaveElements task

Tags: plugin-development, elementcriteriamodel, performance, events

I've got a plugin that does a thing when an entry is resaved. It works great. However I need it to fire for every single entry to build some data.

```
craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) {
    // Do the thing
});
```

Why does running a **ResaveElements** task not fire this yet saving an entry does? Updating a section to cause all of the entries in that section to update doesn't either.

Is there a way I can bulk trigger this to fire outside of me having to write my own script to manually do it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the ResaveElements task calls `craft()->elements->saveElement()` directly, instead of going through the element specific save method (like `craft()->entries->saveEntry()`.

You'll want to listen to the [onSaveElement](https://craftcms.com/docs/plugins/events-reference#elements-onSaveElement) event, check that it's an Entry you're looking at, then perform any specific business logic that you need.